# PHP: Is there a function to parse a text surrounded by quotes as a string?

Tags: php, string, parsing, escaping, quotes

I'm looking for simple way to parse a text surrounded by quotes (`"` or `'`) as a string where the same quote character can be used within that string (escaped by a backslash `\`).
So basically the same thing PHP does internally when parsing strings. Python has `literal_eval` for that (thanks @georg for pointing that out).

### Example

**Input**

`"This is a \"cool\" string"`

**Output**

`This is a "cool" string`

Using `eval` would work, but I'd like to avoid using it. Example below

```
$str = '"This is a \\"cool\\" string"';
$a = eval("return $str;");
var_dump($a); 
// Output: string(23) "This is a "cool" string"
```

Is there something built-in?

### Edit

Wow, I really thought "parsing a string" with the explanation "So basically the same thing PHP does internally when parsing strings" would be an obvious request :D

Think of a more advanced example:

**Input**

`"This is a \"cool\" string that contains one backslash \\ or maybe two in a row \\\\"`

**Output**

`This is a "cool" string that contains one backslash \ or maybe two in a row \\`

The corresponding PHP code would be:

```
$input = '"This is a \\"cool\\" string that contains one backslash \\\\ or maybe two in a row \\\\\\\\"';
$output = parse_quoted_string($str);
var_dump($output);
// string(78) "This is a "cool" string that contains one backslash \ or maybe two in a row \\"
```

I'm looking for suitable function for `parse_quoted_string()`.

Comment: Just echo your cool string and it will show what you are showing as required output. Unless I didn't get it?

Comment: `echo "This is a \"cool\" string";` That shows your desired output, no?

Comment: @georg works, but only for double quotes. `'This is a \'cool\' string'` will fail

Comment: @Hanky yes it does, but I the input it `'"This is a \"cool\" string"'` so you'd still have to "parse" it first

Comment: Added some more info on the question with a more complex example.

Comment: @Hirnhamster: you gotta do some programming then. There's no such thing in php like python's `literal_eval`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It's always helpful to have an example for what you're looking in another language.

Answer (score 1):

Input string is JSON - simply use `json_decode`.

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/CS4MLBEV)

Comment: +1 This solution was also mentioned as comment by @george. It work's (and will suit my needs for now) but it will fail when the quotation character is a single quote instead of a double quote since JSON only recognizes double quotes as quotation character. I'd still like to keep the question open as it's not a full solution to the question.

Comment: Otherwise u need regular expression.

Comment: na.. more a parser. Regex is probably not the most suitable thing for parsing.

Comment: The only solution left is eval.